# Importing sequelize : "The requested module does not provide an export named 'sequelize' "

Tags: node.js, graphql, sequelize.js

fairly new to node, Apollo-Server and sequelize. After installing sequelize via npm , I try to import it but it keeps returning

```
SyntaxError: The requested module './models/index.js'
does not provide an export named 'sequelize'
```

and I can't figure out why

Server.js

```
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone';
import { sequelize } from './models/index.js';
// The GraphQL schema
const typeDefs = `#graphql
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`;

// A map of functions which return data for the schema.
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'world',
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server);
console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`)
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => console.log('Database connected!!'))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

./models/index.js

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const process = require('process');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (
      file.indexOf('.') !== 0 &&
      file !== basename &&
      file.slice(-3) === '.js' &&
      file.indexOf('.test.js') === -1
    );
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

I positively made my package.json have "type": "module" in it and positively installed node, I tried `const { sequelize } = require('./models')` but it obviously doesn't work with the "type": "module"

Comment: Why not just `export { sequelize }` from `models/index.js`? Nothing to do with apollo-server by the way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried 
module.exports = { sequelize } on index.js
and 
import { sequelize } from './models/index.js'; on server.js
but still get the same answer

Answer (score 0):

Try a normal ES6 export as follows:

```
export const sequelize = config.use_env_variable ? 
  new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config) :
  new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
```

In `models/index.js`